How to make my system add calculate overall thread time?
The below code runs a version of my system using multithreading, this method runs multiple times throughout the systems use, everytime it runs the time it takes to complete this method gets added to the last time it took, then at the end iterations, the system calcs how many iterations it has done and divides (all the added times) / the number of iterations = average time for each iteration. but the time keeps added each individual thread time, so 5 threads take 2ms and 5 take 10ms, instead of time being 10ms (as greatest time) it displays 60ms (5*2ms)+(5*10ms).
protected void runParallelVersion() {
        
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            
            threads[i] = new Thread(new GameUpdateThread(grid, tempGrid, startRowArray[i], endRowArray[i]));
            threads[i].start();
        }
        
        
        threadJoiner(threads);
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {

            threads[i] = new Thread(new CopyArrayUpdateGuiThread(grid, tempGrid, cellPanels, startRowArray[i], endRowArray[i]));
            threads[i].start();
        }
        
        threadJoiner(threads);
    
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
generationTimeCalc(totalTime);

    private void generationTimeCalc(long time) {
        if (generationCounter >= GENERATIONS) {
            averageGenTime = (averageGenTime + time) / GENERATIONS;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(averageGenTime);
            averageGenTime = averageGenTime + time;
        }


Well, if you're asking about a calculation you should add that calculation here. What you've shown seems to basically be one of the iterations you describe, i.e. you run 2x n threads and take the time that takes (assuming threadJoiner() waits for all threads to have completed). So totalTime shows the time of one such run - that's it. It seems you didn't share the actual part you're asking about.

changed to add the calc, section

Taking a wider look, you're attempting to measure how long a thing takes. You cannot do it this way - see the link @daniu wrote. That obviates your question. Voting to close.

This, (averageGenTime + time) / GENERATIONS; isn't how averaging works. What is GENERATIONS As it doesn't change anywhere in this code is it perchance 1? Which would mean your "averageGen" time is just going to be the sum. You also have a threading issue where you can skip updates of averageGen because one thread will be reading the value, then another thread will update the value, then a stale value will be written.
